# Find single occurrence of matched and non-matched records from has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, has-many-through

I have 3 Postgres table

1. groups
2. groups_favourites
3. favourites

The structure for those 3 tables are:

```
groups
--------------------------
| id |  name   | user_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | Group A |   100   |
| 2  | Group B |   100   |
| 3  | Group C |   100   |
| 4  | Group D |   100   |
--------------------------

favourites_groups
-------------------------------
| id | group_id | favorite_id |
-------------------------------
| 1  |  2       | 10          |
| 2  |  2       | 12          |
| 3  |  2       | 14          |
| 4  |  2       | 15          |
| 5  |  2       | 16          |
| 6  |  3       | 12          |
| 7  |  4       | 10          |
| 8  |  4       | 11          |
| 9  |  4       | 12          |
| 10 |  4       | 13          |
-------------------------------
UNIQUE INDEX ON [group_id, favorite_id]

favourites
-------------------------------
| id | product_id  | user_id  |
-------------------------------
| 10 |    1000     |   100    |
| 11 |    1001     |   100    |
| 12 |    1002     |   100    |
| 13 |    1003     |   100    |
| 14 |    1004     |   100    |
| 15 |    1005     |   100    |
| 16 |    1006     |   100    |
-------------------------------
```

I am using **Ruby on Rails** on backend and the relationship between these 3 tables are setup via `has_many :through` association

The result I would like to accomplish is: For a given Product and User, I would like to find all groups that have entries in `favorite_groups` table + All groups that do not have entry in `favorites_groups` table.

Let's say for `user_id = 100` AND `product_id = 1000`, the result would be:

```
| group_id | group_name | favorite_id | product_id |
----------------------------------------------------
|    1     |  Group A   |    NULL     |    NULL    |
|    2     |  Group B   |     10      |    1000    |
|    3     |  Group C   |    NULL     |    NULL    |
|    4     |  Group D   |     10      |    1000    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Another use-case is for `user_id = 100` AND `product_id = 1002`, the result would be:

```
| group_id | group_name | favorite_id | product_id |
----------------------------------------------------
|    1     |  Group A   |    NULL     |    NULL    |
|    2     |  Group B   |     12      |    1002    |
|    3     |  Group C   |     12      |    1002    |
|    4     |  Group D   |     12      |    1002    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

The current SQL I am using is giving me 1 row of `NULL` `favorite_id` and `product_id` and 1 row of matched `favorite_id` and `product_id`

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (group_id, favorite_id, product_id) groups.id AS group_id, groups.name AS group_name, favorites.id AS favorite_id, favorites.product_id AS product_id
FROM groups
LEFT JOIN favorite_groups ON favorite_groups.group_id = groups.id
LEFT JOIN favorites ON favorites.id = favorite_groups.favorite_id AND favorites.product_id = 1002
WHERE groups.user_id = 100
```

Because of results returned by this query, I have to work extra to iterate over each row and prepare the result set that I want.

Is there a better approach of doing this?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something odd in your model.  The relationship between `groups.name` and the `user_id` that shows up in both `groups` and `favourites` is unclear. The `unique` constraint on `favourites_groups` should make the `user_id` in `favourites` unnecessary, so I added a commented-out `join` condition.

Please try this query to see if it returns what you need:

```
select g.id as group_id, g.name as group_name
  from groups g
  left join favourites_groups fg
    on fg.group_id = g.id
  left join favourites f
    on f.id = fg.favorite_id
 --  and f.user_id = g.user_id 
 where g.user_id = 100
   and f.product_id = 1002
;
```

**Update**
Sorry about that.  This should return what you want:

```
select g.id as group_id, g.name as group_name,
       max(f.id) as favorite_id, 
       max(f.product_id) as product_id
  from groups g
  left join favourites_groups fg 
    on fg.group_id = g.id
  left join favourites f 
    on f.id = fg.favorite_id
   and f.product_id = 1000
 where g.user_id = 100
 group by g.id, g.name
 order by g.id;
```

Comment: Thanks @mike-organek for your response but the query you have provided is giving me only those groups that have entries in `favorite_groups` table if Group A does not have any favorite_groups, then this query is not returning Group A

Comment: @PuneetPandey Sorry about that.  Please see the update.

Comment: Thanks @mike-organek your solution worked. Just curious to know how optimise it is? I mean, I ran for few records and it worked well but what if there are hundreds or thousands of rows - will the same work without observing any slowness?

Comment: @PuneetPandey  It will slow down with volume, but I do not think that thousands of rows will slow it much.  If it does get bad, then you need to make sure that the `favourites.id` is indexed (should be already since it looks like the PK) and `groups.user_id` is indexed.

Comment: hey @mike-organek yes both the fields are indexed. Will see how it goes. Thank you so much for this